# CRYSTAL REPORT What is x:=x;?

Tags: crystal-reports, colon-equals

What does this mean in Crystal Report XI?

`x:=x;`

The whole formula is

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared numbervar x;
x:=x;
```

But it doesn't give any output.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `Shared` scope is ONLY necessary when one needs to pass a value to/from a sub-report.  `Global` is a better option.  If a scope isn't specified, `Global` is assumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x:=x;` section would normally be used to set the value of `x` eg:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared numbervar x;
x:=10;
```

Running this code sets the variable and returns the value set (as long as only a single variable is set), to also return the value of the variable you can add:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared numbervar x;
x:=10;
x
```

Or if the variable is set elsewhere, to return the value you can do:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared numbervar x;
x
```

Comment: The line `x:=10;` will most definitely return a value (I just tested it).  It is not necessary to all the line that contains just the variable `x`.

Comment: @craig, I consider it 'best practise' to specify which value to return, as you often find users declaring and setting more than one variable in a  single formula, if you leave off the last line it will cause problems. However I have edited to correct the term.